# How can I check on the progress of an application?

Tags: hiring-process, applications, follow-up

I submitted a programming test and job application a week ago today. I received an email back thanking me for my submission (the day after) and that it has been handed to the people who will be a) reviewing my code b) reviewing my resume.

My question is: how long should I wait to follow this up? Is a week okay or should I give it another week? When I do follow it up, how do I word my email? I should note that I've tried searching for this job listing again on the jobs website I found it on - and it doesn't appear in search results. However, you can browse directly to the job ad.

I don't want to be annoying, but I'm really edgy waiting for a call/email!

Comment: I wrote a long answer on Programmers about why applicants don't always get feedback as quickly or with as much detail as they want. You may find it relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25888/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-reasons-after-rejected-after-the-interview/25990#25990

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes email them, be polite and come across as being genuinely interested in the job.

Review the job ad/posting to see if there are clues about deadlines. Sometimes they wait until all the test results are in, before determining who moves on to the next round.

In the meantime keep looking for jobs. You don't have to wait for word from one company before applying to another company. This is especially true when there are multiple test and interviews involved in the hiring process. Even if this company wants you they could still be weeks or months away from their expected start date for the new employee.

The part of the ad about:

> "no calls please, only applicants who complete code test will be considered".

is telling candidates to follow the instructions, take the test, and we will let you know.

Assuming you followed the rest of the instructions, then a polite inquisitive email should not be a problem.

This does assume that you do know who to email. Some companies only provide a generic web interface to upload a resume. The resumes are then stored in a database linked to the position number. The thank you email back from the company when you submitted the test may be from an automated email address that is never read.

Comment: Luckily for me a real person responded thanking me for my submission the day after I submitted it.. so I shall reply to that person :) Thanks!

Comment: but only 1 email, do not become a pest.

Answer (score 3):

If a week has passed, it is very likely that you didn't interest them. In the best case they might have put you in the end of their list of candidates. It is less likely (but still possible) that your application has been lost somewhere.

If the job posting didn't say that there should be no personal calls and/or emails, you could try contacting them to find out about the job. It will show that you are highly interested in the position. The worst thing that might happen is that they will say they've already hired someone else, or will ask you to wait until they contact you (in this case we go to the beginning, except that you shouldn't contact them again not to be too nasty).

Comment: The job ad said "no calls please, only applicants who complete code test will be considered". Would that indicate that they didn't want people to call **BEFORE** they submit their application? Or not call at all? Perhaps an email would be better?

Comment: If they said No calls, don't call. Email is fine