# 2 weeks ago my recruitment agency told me I have a job offer, but nothing concrete yet

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom

Two weeks ago, my technical recruitment agency told me that I would receive a good offer from an expanding company.  I am in touch with the recruitment agency. They told me that the company is genuinely interested and there are delays because of external HR. I am starting to get impatient.

Is there anything I can do to speed up the process? Should I look elsewhere?

I'm in the UK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check on the progress of an application?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/how-can-i-check-on-the-progress-of-an-application)

Answer (score 7):

Continue interviewing until you have an offer in hand. "A verbal contract is not worth the paper it's printed on." Especially when the person telling you this is the recruiter, who has no authority to commit to a contract.

Until you get the offer itself, you do not have anything you can even partially count on. And while they're dithering, you may be able to line up a better offer, or at least one you can use to try to convince them to improve their offer.

Comment: Short, but sweet, answer. Being told that you will receive an offer - and a good offer, at that! - is great news! But until you actually *do* receive it, you can't accept it, and until you accept it, keep looking!!