# Checking on an application after a month of radio silence

Tags: hiring-process, applications

I have applied for a job mid-September with a closing date of 18th September. I then emailed the recruitment team on 6th October to understand a bit more about the status of my application, they said:
"A final decision has not been made with regards to your application. We will be in touch once a decision has been made"

It has now been a month and still no reply, Can I email them again to find out? is it best to just wait as Iam told the process for such big company can take up to 3 months?

Plus, on their website my application is still showing as "Submitted"

Comment: Welcome to the site elodie. I feel like your questions may be answered by some of the answers on this question: [How can I check on the progress of an application?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/how-can-i-check-on-the-progress-of-an-application?rq=1). Can you have a look and see if that's the case? If not, could you explain (in a comment or an [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/57212/edit) to your post) how your question is different?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely email them for a status update but usually a big company will not send emails out on application status for everyone. Who knows, they might reach out to you months later.