# Asked for availability for an interview, but not scheduled yet

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I had reached out to a firm's partner on LinkedIn about one of their open positions.

We had a good chat, followed by him asking about my availability over the next two weeks for an interview. I reached out to him and gave him the dates and times at which I would be available.

A week has passed since, however the interview has not yet been scheduled. How should I approach him about this, especially since I had given out dates for this week as well?

This is a pretty new firm (~10 people), but the job and the industry sector which it is in is very exciting to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: Hey, I checked the link, however my question is a bit different. I have not interviewed with this firm yet - my last talk with the Partner of the firm was about him asking me to give him my availability over the next two weeks, and that was it. We haven't moved forward to the interviewing yet.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/how-can-i-check-on-the-progress-of-an-application?noredirect=1&lq=1 

How about that?

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the point where you think you have new information for them, then contact them.

They asked for dates, and now those dates are either passing by, or you may need to make adjustments because other meetings are happening that conflict with the original list.

Just reach out to them. Soon your list of dates will be worthless. So you will have to contact them.

Contacting them when you have nothing for them, or when the deadline you agreed to hasn't expired, can be seen as pestering. But that isn't your case. You have information for them, and it might revive your chances of an interview.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wait another week, then reach out with a new set of dates that you are available and inquire if you could expect an interview to be scheduled in the next few weeks.

No need to read too much into the delay. There is a lot going on at the moment.